# Discontinuous functions and sets

Tags: real-analysis

I'm looking for an example of a discontinuous function $f: \mathbb{R}\ \to\ \mathbb{R}\ $ and an open set $\mathit{U}\ \subset\ \mathbb{R}\ $ such that the preimage $f^{-1}(\mathit{U}) $ is not open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & \text{if} & x<0, \\
1 & \text{if} & x\ge 0.
\end{array}\right.
$$
Then
$f^{-1}(0,\infty)=[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$ f(x) = {\begin{cases}
        1 & x=1\\
        0 & \text{else}
        \end{cases}}$$
And Let 
$$ U = \{ x \space | \space  0.5 < x < 1.5 \} $$
Clearly $U$ is open and
$$ f^{-1}(U) = \{1 \} $$
Which is not open.